# Change values in excel file from values of other excel using python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have data

```
   id
30046
30049
30040
30046
```

And next excel

```
     id                mail
30049  natusya_89_2009@mail.ru  
30046  fresh_tea@mail.ru    
30040  sedoi7072@mail.ru
```

I want to change id from 1 file to mail from 2 excel. 
Desire output

```
id  
fresh_tea@mail.ru   
natusya_89_2009@mail.ru 
sedoi7072@mail.ru
fresh_tea@mail.ru
```

I try

```
for (id1, id2, mail) in zip(ids1, ids2, mails):
    if id1 == id2:
        ids1.replace(id1, mail)
```

Comment: Do you want to change the Excel files or just print out the emails?

Comment: @doctorlove, I need to change df, `df  = pd.read_excel('name.xlsx')`, but don't want to change excel

Comment: OK, can you add 'df' to the code above? It's not mentioned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) column `id` in `df1` by `Serie` created by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) from `df2`:

```
print (df1)
      id
0  30046
1  30049
2  30040
3  30046

print (df2)
      id                     mail
0  30049  natusya_89_2009@mail.ru
1  30046        fresh_tea@mail.ru
2  30040        sedoi7072@mail.ru

df1['id'] = df1.id.map(df2.set_index('id')['mail'])
print (df1)
                        id
0        fresh_tea@mail.ru
1  natusya_89_2009@mail.ru
2        sedoi7072@mail.ru
3        fresh_tea@mail.ru
```

Comment: and may suggest to me to the same example? If I have in columns with quantity of hours, for example `3` and I should add it to column with string like `17/Jun/2016:06:25:05`, i want to get `17/Jun/2016:09:25:05`, i can use your example, but what I shoud do, to make it `datetime` type

Comment: I think you can create new question, please add sample and desired output if simple `pd.to_datetime(df['date_col'])` doesnt work.

Comment: I add new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37990019/change-column-in-df-from-column-from-another

Comment: Can you say, I have similar question, I should change one column from another, but I should change that and to new value add last. I do `df['id'] = df.id.map(status.set_index('mail')['status' + ' ' + df.id])` but it returns `ValueError: cannot index with vector containing NA / NaN values`