# Change column in df from column from another

Tags: python, excel, datetime, pandas, dataframe

I have data:

```
                 date                      id 
0     2016-06-17 06:25:05    yans.bouts@yandex.ru    
1     2016-06-17 06:25:07    yans.bouts@yandex.ru       
2     2016-06-17 06:25:10    titovtanya@yandex.ru         
3     2016-06-17 06:25:11    titovtanya@yandex.ru
```

Other data

```
Email,UTC shift
yans.bouts@yandex.ru,5
inkin_sam@mail.ru,3
titovtanya@yandex.ru,3
dasha.dasha.kovaleva@mail.ru,2
```

I need to add `UTC shift` to first file `date` to `hours`.
Desire output:

```
                     date                      id 
0     2016-06-17 11:25:05    yans.bouts@yandex.ru    
1     2016-06-17 11:25:07    yans.bouts@yandex.ru       
2     2016-06-17 09:25:10    titovtanya@yandex.ru         
3     2016-06-17 09:25:11    titovtanya@yandex.ru
```

I convert `date` to datetime, but I don't know, how convert `UTC shift` to hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need first convert [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) column `date` if `dtype` is not `datetime`, [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) by columns `id` and `Email`. Then convert [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html) column `UTC shift`, add to `date` and last [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) unnecessary columns:

```
import pandas as pd


df1 = pd.DataFrame({'date': {0: '2016-06-17 06:25:05', 1: '2016-06-17 06:25:07', 2: '2016-06-17 06:25:10', 3: '2016-06-17 06:25:11'}, 
                      'id': {0: 'yans.bouts@yandex.ru', 1: 'yans.bouts@yandex.ru', 2: 'titovtanya@yandex.ru', 3: 'titovtanya@yandex.ru'}})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Email': {0: 'yans.bouts@yandex.ru', 1: 'inkin_sam@mail.ru', 2: 'titovtanya@yandex.ru', 3: 'dasha.dasha.kovaleva@mail.ru'}, 
                    'UTC shift': {0: 5, 1: 3, 2: 3, 3: 2}})

print (df1)
                  date                    id
0  2016-06-17 06:25:05  yans.bouts@yandex.ru
1  2016-06-17 06:25:07  yans.bouts@yandex.ru
2  2016-06-17 06:25:10  titovtanya@yandex.ru
3  2016-06-17 06:25:11  titovtanya@yandex.ru

print (df2)
                          Email  UTC shift
0          yans.bouts@yandex.ru          5
1             inkin_sam@mail.ru          3
2          titovtanya@yandex.ru          3
3  dasha.dasha.kovaleva@mail.ru          2
```

```
df1['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1.date)

df = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on='id', right_on='Email')
df['date'] += pd.to_timedelta(df['UTC shift'], unit='H')
df.drop(['Email','UTC shift'], axis=1, inplace=True)
print (df)
                 date                    id
0 2016-06-17 11:25:05  yans.bouts@yandex.ru
1 2016-06-17 11:25:07  yans.bouts@yandex.ru
2 2016-06-17 09:25:10  titovtanya@yandex.ru
3 2016-06-17 09:25:11  titovtanya@yandex.ru
```

Comment: for some values it returns `NaT`

Comment: What are this problematic values?

Comment: I convert `df1['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1.date)` without problem. But to 24 str it works well, but to 11000 it returns `NaT`

Comment: `11000` ?  value in column `date` is only `11000`? Then what is desired output?

Comment: I have 11000 strings in `df`. so I have 11000 values in `df1['date']` and I should to convert all of this

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong with my solution before - `merge` is very important and now i hope it can works/

Comment: Now it print only 2 strings, but theu are not correct

Comment: to `2016-06-17 06:25:05` with `UTC shift = 3` it returns `2016-06-17 12:25:05`

Comment: Interesting, now I add to answer sample, please check it if this works.

Comment: Maybe there is problem with duplicates in `email` column. What return `print (df2.Email.is_unique)`  ?

Comment: I use `df1` instead df. And now it works well! thank you!)

Comment: Can you say, I need to do this operation with other data, I use your code, but it returns `Empty DataFrame
Columns: [member_id, application_name, event_address, event_time, event_duration, Email, UTC shift]
Index: []`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115527/discussion-between-jezrael-and-arseniy-krupenin).

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
df['date'] += pd.Timedelta(df['UTC shift'], unit='H')
```